# Algorithm for intersection point between two vectors

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I'm trying to learn [Computational Geometry](https://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=features&d2=091806) and this formula isn't obvious to me.

Hint: `cross` is related to the cross product of two vectors.

```
# Returns intersection of infinite lines ab and pq (or undefined)
point intersect(point a, point b, point p, point q):
    d1 = cross(p - a, b - a)
    d2 = cross(q - a, b - a)
    return (d1 * q - d2 * p) / (d1 - d2)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Do you know what the `cross` function does?  Do you understand what the `intersect` function does?

Comment: Thanks for response .... I mean i need the proof of correctness of this method ... I try some values and it works but how ? I always solve it by solving two algebraic equations of the two lines .

Comment: I'd suggest looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect

Comment: helpful, thanks .